# Json array is being converted to string when sending data to api. how to remove it?

Tags: android

"[[{"NameOfNote":"P","Height":"0","Alteration":"100","Frequency":"0.0","Finger":"0","String":"0","Time":"16","Dotted_Note":"0","ToBeDisplayed":"true"},{"NameOfNote":"P","Height":"0","Alteration":"100","Frequency":"0.0","Finger":"0","String":"0","Time":"16","Dotted_Note":"0","ToBeDisplayed":"true"}],[{"NameOfNote":"P","Height":"0","Alteration":"100","Frequency":"0.0","Finger":"0","String":"0","Time":"16","Dotted_Note":"0","ToBeDisplayed":"true"},{"NameOfNote":"P","Height":"0","Alteration":"100","Frequency":"0.0","Finger":"0","String":"0","Time":"16","Dotted_Note":"0","ToBeDisplayed":"true"}]]"

Above is my output

Below is my implementation

```
 var mainJson = JSONArray()
    for(i in 0..song_result.size-1){
        var innerJSONArray = JSONArray()
        for (j in 0..song_result[i].size -1){
            var obj = JSONObject()
            try {
                obj.put("NameOfNote", song_result[i][j].NameOfNote)
                obj.put("Height", song_result[i][j].Height)
                obj.put("Alteration", song_result[i][j].Alteration)
                obj.put("Frequency", song_result[i][j].Frequency)
                obj.put("Finger", song_result[i][j].Finger)
                obj.put("String", song_result[i][j].String)
                obj.put("Time", song_result[i][j].Time)
                obj.put("Dotted_Note", song_result[i][j].Dotted_Note)
                obj.put("ToBeDisplayed", song_result[i][j].ToBeDisplayed)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            innerJSONArray.put(obj)
        }
        mainJson.put(innerJSONArray)
    }
```

Comment: nothing wrong with that Json is String

Comment: That's not wrong. It's good to send data to API in the form of a string. You need to add some code to change to the required datatype on the receiving side. In the future, you need to encrypt the string when sending data from android to API for security. Open data can be easily accessed using packet monitoring apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json is not encoded well let me solve your problem
add the gson lib from [here](https://github.com/google/gson)
add this class

```
data class Root (

@SerializedName("NameOfNote") val nameOfNote : String,
@SerializedName("Height") val height : Int,
@SerializedName("Alteration") val alteration : Int,
@SerializedName("Frequency") val frequency : Double,
@SerializedName("Finger") val finger : Int,
@SerializedName("String") val string : Int,
@SerializedName("Time") val time : Int,
@SerializedName("Dotted_Note") val dotted_Note : Int,
@SerializedName("ToBeDisplayed") val toBeDisplayed : Boolean
```

)

Call this method

```
    val obj= Root(nameOfNote = "name",height = 9,alteration = 7,frequency = 7.8,finger = 7,string = 7,time = 8,dotted_Note = 9,toBeDisplayed = false)
    val json=   Gson ().toJson(obj)
```

You can do this in for loop just rember to add in string dont replace

Comment: Thnkxx bro.Worked like charm. Thankxx :)